# Getting null values in gridview while using volley in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library to get data from server in android. I am using two request to retrieve data. First request should retrieve all data before second one. So i used Priority to process in order. Now First request retrieved all data before second one. But i am doing some calculation after two request process. The calculation is done using the result of above two request. The problem is, once i load calculation part got executed, after that my data retrieved from server. So i am getting null .So what is the way to do my calculation after my request part.

Here is my code:

```
final Priority priority = Priority.HIGH;
    JsonArrayRequest req1 = new JsonArrayRequest("http://xxexample.com/android/prabalam.php",
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response1) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response1.toString());
                    //msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    jArray1=response1;
                    try
                    {
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray1.length();i++)
                    {
                    jObj1=jArray1.getJSONObject(i);

                    name=jObj1.getString("name");
                    aname.add(name);
                    roll=jObj1.getString("roll");
                    aroll.add(roll);
                    intro=jObj1.getString("intro");
                    aintro.add(intro);
                    mobile_no=jObj1.getString("mobile_no");
                    amobileno.add(mobile_no);
                    ma_no=jObj1.getString("manager_no");
                    amano.add(ma_no);
                    s_no=jObj1.getString("s_no");
                    asno.add(s_no);

                    //hideProgressDialog1();
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("caught exception prabalam.php"+e.getMessage());
                    }

                    System.out.println(" ;name"+aname);
                    System.out.println(";roll.."+aroll);
                    System.out.println(";intro"+aintro);
                    //msgResponse.setText(mimg.get(0));

                    //ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

                    // If you are using NetworkImageView
                    //imgNetWorkView.setImageUrl(mimg.get(0), imageLoader);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    //msgResponse.setText(error.getMessage());
                    //hideProgressDialog1();
                }
            }){
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req1,
            tag_json_arry);


    //showProgressDialog1();
    final Priority priority1 = Priority.NORMAL;
    JsonArrayRequest req2 = new JsonArrayRequest("http://iexample.com/android/pr_images.php",
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response2) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response2.toString());
                    //msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    jArray2=response2;
                    try
                    {
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray2.length();i++)
                    {
                    jObj2=jArray2.getJSONObject(i);
                    img=jObj2.getString("images");
                    images.add(img);
                    snoo=jObj2.getString("s_no");
                    sno.add(snoo);
                    pnoo=jObj2.getString("p_no");
                    pno.add(pnoo);

                    //hideProgressDialog1();
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("caught exception pr_images.php"+e1.getMessage());
                    }

                    System.out.println("images name"+images);
                    System.out.println("sno.."+sno);
                    System.out.println("pno.."+pno);


                    //msgResponse.setText(mimg.get(0));

                    //ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

                    // If you are using NetworkImageView
                    //imgNetWorkView.setImageUrl(mimg.get(0), imageLoader);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    //msgResponse.setText(error.getMessage());
                    //hideProgressDialog1();
                }
            })
    {
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return priority1;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req2,
            tag_json_arry);     


String v2=null;
        for(int u=0;u<pno.size();u++)
        {
            String v1=pno.get(u);
            String vpho=images.get(u);

            if((fno1.size())==0)
            {
                fphoto1.add(vpho);
                fno1.add(v1);
            }
            else
            {
                Boolean gh=false;

                if(v2.equals(v1))
                {
                    gh=false;
                }

                for(int k=0;k<ff1.size();k++)
                {
                String wee=ff1.get(k);
                if(wee.equals(v1))
                {
                    gh=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    gh=true;
                }
                }
                if(gh)
                {
                    fphoto1.add(vpho);
                    fno1.add(v1);
                }
            }
            ff1=fno1;
            v2=v1;
        }

        if(a.equals("nulll"))
        {
            for(int z=0;z<aroll.size();z++)
            {
                String valall=aroll.get(z);
            if(valall.equals("New Face Male"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("New face male dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("New Face Female"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("New face female.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Child"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("child.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);
            }
            else if(valall.equals("Villan"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("villan.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Comedy"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("comedy.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Film Director"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("film director dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Lyric Writer"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("lyric writer dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Cinematographer"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("cinematographer.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Cine Designer"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("cine designer.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Art Director"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("art director.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Music Director"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("music director.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);
            }
            else if(valall.equals("Play Back Singer"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("play back singer.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }
            else if(valall.equals("Still Photographer"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));  

                System.out.println("photographer.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);
            }
            else if(valall.equals("Stunt Director"))
            {
                dname.add(aname.get(z));
                dphoto.add(fphoto1.get(z));
                droll.add(aroll.get(z));
                dsno.add(asno.get(z));

                System.out.println("stunt director.. dname"+dname);
                System.out.println("dphoto"+dphoto);
                System.out.println("droll.."+droll);
                System.out.println("dsno.."+dsno);

            }

            }
            resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();
            resim_list.addAll(dphoto);
            resim_name=new ArrayList<String>();
            resim_name.addAll(dname);
            rolll=new ArrayList<String>();
            rolll.addAll(droll);
            mobile=new ArrayList<String>();
            mobile.addAll(dsno);

            System.out.println("resim list"+resim_list);
            System.out.println("resim name"+resim_name);
            System.out.println("rolll.."+rolll);
            System.out.println("mobile.."+mobile);

        }

}
```

When i use basic method to retrieve data, it works fine.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) example for calling images and data using `volley`

Comment: It is same as above code mentioned. Can you mention mistake which i had done in above code.

Comment: i have posted logcat as answer.Please check it out.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal Is there any other solution to it?

Comment: You need to run it synchronized with your server response so either by thread or Asynktask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67615/discussion-between-himanshu-agarwal-and-divya).